# Making currently active menu not working

Tags: php, jquery, css, menu

I have a `menu.php` as below :

```
<?php $menu = 
'<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="home.php"><li>HOME</li></a>
        <a href="about.php"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
        <a href="works.php"><li>WORKS</li></a>
        <a href="clients.php"><li>CLIENTS</li></a>
        <a href="contact.php"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>    
</div>';
?>
```

Now I want to make the background and font color same as when I hover the list. For this I have added a jQuery to add a class called `active`, but its not working ! My jquery and CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function(){
    //alert('Active');
        $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS :

```
#menu li:hover
{
    background:#ffca00;
    color:#2e2f34;
    padding:16px 12px;

}
#menu li.active
{
    background:#ffca00;
    color:#2e2f34;
    padding:16px 12px;  
}
```

Whats wrong ? is my jquery is wrong?

UPDATE:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        a//lert(this);
        $('#menu ul li').addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#menu
{
    width:450px;
    margin-left:400px;
    background:#000;
}
#menu ul
{
    padding:18px;   
}
#menu li{ 
    display:inline; 
    list-style:none; 
    padding:18px 12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#menu a
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#menu li:hover {
    background:#ffca00;
    color:#2e2f34;
    padding:16px 12px;
}
.active {
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ffca00;
    color:#2e2f34;
    padding:16px 12px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul> <a href="activemenu.html"><li>HOME</li></a>
         <a href="activemenu2.html"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
        <a href="activemenu3.html"><li>ABOUT</li></a>

    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've several errors in your HTML. The children of a ul must be LI, not A. So the LI wrap the A. Then, it's useless to have the menu as a string, just close the php tag, put your menu and then reopen for further eleaborations

Comment: I wanted to show the background color and link the whole `li` when hover the `li` , not only the `anchor` text !

Comment: Regardless of what you wanted to do, the syntax is still wrong. Once you had a proper syntax you can think of how to achieve your goal.

Comment: try out my answer it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/XEy4s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/XEy4s/

`$(this).parent()` is `a tag` but we need `ul tag` so we use `$(this).parent().parent()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**New jS code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loc = $(location).attr('href');
    var n = loc.split("/");
    var n1 = loc.split("/").length;
    var on_page = n[n1 - 1];
    var new_page = on_page.split("?");
    $('#menu ul a').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('href') == new_page[0]) {
            $(this).find('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: well, you answer is the same as Lucas's.

Comment: yeah, we made the same logic

Comment: So delete your answer then, because two answer of the same logic are useless.

Comment: i have explained why i used $(this).parent().parent() instead of $(this).parent()

Comment: Strangely in my case its not working ! I wrote the same jquery and css ! Please check : http://visheshgroup.net/testing/works.php

Comment: you have two $(document).ready(function () one for fancy box and another for this.So you paste this code $('#menu ul li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });  inside the first document.ready function and remove the second document.ready function

Comment: Well I even removed the fancy box jquery code, still getting the same result !!

Comment: declare in css active class as .active {..} not as #menu li.active {..} i tested on your site this will work

Comment: I make local files as in updated question, but not working :( dont know whats wrong with me . Please check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33625/discussion-between-tushar-gupta-and-nitish)

Answer (score 2):

It's not `$(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');`
 but `$(this).parent().parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');`

So the full jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu ul li').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').parent().parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

But, maybe, you want to change of page, keeping the active class to your li. And in this case, it's not jquery but php that you have to use.

Comment: Hi, sadly this code is also not working. Please have a look
http://visheshgroup.net/testing/
I have added the `jquery` for `WORKS`.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you want to do. You want to change of page, but adding the active class to your li.

Comment: Ye. so that the class `.active` is added to the `li` and I can do some css to make it active :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery is correct, but the HTML is invalid. It should be:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="works.php">WORKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="clients.php">CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

With your current HTML, `$(this).parent()` will select the `<a>` parent of the `<li>` clicked on, and `$(this).parent().find('li.active')` will only ever find `<li>` with `class="active"` elements inside the *clicked* element. Whereas you want to find `li.active` starting at the the `<ul>`.

Changing the HTML will make the jQuery `$(this).parent()` find the parent `<ul>` and the remaining jQuery will work as expected.